# programm in c (go a round in a room)

Tags: c, loops, printf

I have a little problem with a C-programm, I wrote. It should be like "you go in a room.. is there a wall? no? then move on.. is there a wall? yes? then turn around" and so on. I am stucked, I go in the room and turn around but do not know how to go further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char answer[2];
answer[0] = "Y";
answer[1] = "N";


do
{
printf("Move!\n");
printf("Is there a wall?\n");
scanf("%s",answer);
}
while (answer[0] != 'Y' );
printf("Turn around!");

}
```

I read about loops and ifs, but my head do not make klick.
Thanks for reading,
hjerteblod

Comment: Any decent compiler should have complained when you tried to build that code. A `char` is a *single character*, `"Y"` is a *string* containing *two* characters (the character `'Y'` and the null-terminator character `'\0'`). And since you don't use the array `answer` before you read into it with `scanf`, you don't really need to initialize it.

Comment: On another note, the "turn around" output is printed *after* the loop, not inside. It will not be printed until the user input something other than `'Y'`. And [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) *must* be declared to return an `int`.

Comment: Also, compile your program with `-fsanitize=address`, it will catch out-of-bounds memory accesses.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, what do you mean with "must return an int"? I just started with C and feel like a total newbie.

Comment: Read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book, the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)). See http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: How do you actually learn C? It seems that your source of knowledge needs to get swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to never exit the game. If so, try this code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char answer;

    while(1){
        printf("Move!\n");
        printf("Is there a wall?\n");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        if (answer == 'Y'){
            printf("Turn around!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey ZBay, yeah thank you! But my acutal problem is, that it should not end it I find a wall. Instead it should turn around and find the next wall. Never ending loop I mean

Comment: It was unclear from your code. Hope you have managed to solve it.

Comment: I am sorry, yeah my problem is the loop. It should not stop after one wall, because the room has 4 walls. unfortunately I did not solved it yet

Comment: big thanks, I tried switch cases now but your solution is much more ... handy? thank u!

Answer (score 0):

`"Y"` is a string with two characters, `answer[0]` is a character, you cannot assign a string to a character. So you can change this code like this `answer[0] = 'Y'`.

By the way, you are better to return an int value in the function `main`.

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // your code here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you guapi, I understand it and it helps

Comment: @guapi Yes, since there are no longer relevant and were only conversational. I'll delete mine, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. `"N"` is a string literal, which evaluates to a pointer to the first element of the string literal `"Y"` in memory. If you try to assign it to `answer[0]` you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since you assign a address value to `char` objects.

   The same goes for `answer[1] = "N";`.

   Both assignments, `answer[0] = "Y";` and `answer[1] = "N";` should have give you a warning, like this from GCC:

   > *warning: assignment to `'char'` from `'char *'` makes integer from pointer without a cast*

   Never ignore compiler warnings.
2. You don't need an array at all, use a single char for `answer`.
3. You need an infinite loop for always going further or turning back from a wall, here implemented by `while (1)`.

Note that this is an unfinished algorithm. In a real production program you need a condition to break out of the loop. But just for the sake of your issue, here is want I think you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   char answer;

   while (1)
   {
      printf("Move!\n");
      printf("Is there a wall?\n");

      if ( scanf(" %c", &answer ) != 1 )
      {
          fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
          return 1;
      }

      if ( answer == 'Y' )
      {
          printf("Turn around!\n");
      }
   }  
}
```

---

Side Notes:

- Always check the return value of input functions such as `scanf()` if an error occurred.
- `void main()` is not standard compliant. Use a return type of `int` and declare the parameter list of type `void` instead of to leave it empty.
- I recommend you to read a good C starting book, f.e. [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) by Jens Gustedt or [The C Programming Language Second Edition](http://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf) by the inventors of C.
- For more information about undefined behavior, take a look at this SO question:

  [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)